# Display Contents of Textbox That was created by PHP

Tags: php, html

I would like some help printing what is in a certain textbox that was created by an echo command.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
     $stringTest = $row['Price'];
     $AssetId = $row['AssetId'];
     echo "<center><div> <h3>Cost: ".$stringTest."";
     echo '<form action="" method="get"><input type="text" name="uid">';
     echo "</br><input class='myButton' type='submit' Name='Submit1'     VALUE='I have bought'></a></form>";
     /** ^ Input value I would like to get *//
     echo "<a href='https://www.roblox.com/item-item?id=".$AssetId."' class='myButton'>Buy</a></h3></div></center>"; 
}
```

Comment: you haven't told us what the issue/problem is. and what's with the `VALUE='I have bought'></a>` <<< ?

Comment: Messed up some stuff, fixed that, I still have no clue how to print textbox.

Comment: What information are you trying to get from `input`? The value?

Comment: Yes, the value of the input

Comment: `$_GET['Submit1']`? Doesn't matter if the form was generated by php. it's just an html form on the client, and submits back to the server the same as any OTHER form.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print PHP element in a textbox you should put it in the value tag of the input

```
<?php 
    echo "<input type='text' value='" . $val . "'>"; 
?>
```

Comment: `value='" . $val . '>` missing a quote there

Comment: That's not what I mean. I meant print the value of the textbox.

Comment: @user3743254 well then, you need another piece of code for this. and this answer has a syntax error

Comment: If you want to retrive a var asynchronously you have to do it with Javascript, for example assigning to a div a data-id value and interacting with it with a jQuery query.

Comment: they don't have to use js @GiacomoTorricelli and you still haven't fixed that syntax error yet, *perché?*

Comment: @GiacomoTorricelli I don't know jQuery, nor does my hosting 
server support it.

Comment: @user3743254 man, jQuery is not supported by an Hosting but from the browser of each user in the world, I think you should read some documentation that explain the difference between Server Side and Client Side differences.
Insert the script input

      https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js

Comment: seems I am not getting through here. can you fix the typo in your question or do you feel that is entirely correct and won't cause a parse error? as said what... 15 mins ago. Edit: finalmente, *grazie!*

Answer (score 1):

Use the code below to get the value from `submit`:

```
if(isset($_GET['Submit1'])) {
 echo $_GET['Submit1'];
}
```

When the user clicks `submit`, it will echo the value of it.

Comment: *ahem* => `<form action="" method="get">` = *No love* - [as per original...](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36893338/1)